# Socket based server, control data to send to a specific client

Tags: java, sockets

```
public void sendData(InetAddress address){
        try{
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output.writeObject(TST);
        output.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ee){
            System.out.println("Error : " + ee);
        }
    }
```

The server is a multi-thread.
There is a part of my code to send a object 'TST' out using ObjectOutputStream ,how to control the method to send the object to specific client who have the address i inputted to this method when ?

Comment: The socket is what identifies the destination client uniquely. That's what should be the argument of your method, and not InetAddress.

Comment: Ask the `socket` [who it's connected to](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress()).

Answer (score 0):

Create another Instance of a Connection Oriented TCP Socket and Connect to the Client using it.

You could use the ServerSocket in your Client Program or the Server Program depending on what is convenient to you,but as you have specified an InetAddress over the method argument,
and I guess "socket" is a static instance of either Socket or ServerSocket,if it is an instance of Socket,initialize it as

```
socket=new Socket(address,port);
try{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    output.writeObject(TST);
    output.close();
}
catch(IOException ee){
    System.out.println("Error : " + ee);
}
```

before entering the try block or as soon as you enter the try block before creating the Object Output Stream.

In this case in your Client code create a ServerSocket

```
ServerSocket soc=new ServerSocket(port);
Socket cli=soc.accept();
```

This will help in achieving the task.

Comment: And there is 1 more question,after i need another connection to
the specific client,how can i disconnect it?i have tried to use
socket.close(); but it's wort

Comment: Close the Client Socket before you Close the ServerSocket,that's all i can say,i do not know exactly how you are doing it.